# Array of record initialization

Tags: delphi

I have this type:

```
type
  TFieldRec = array of record
    FieldName: string;
    Value: Variant;
    DataType: TFieldType;
    Data: Pointer;
  end;
```

And the code:

```
var
  FR: TFieldRec;
SetLength(FR, 5);
```

My question: is it **guaranteed** that each record element will be initialize with default values?

```
'', Unassigned, ftUnknown, nil
```

In the debugger I can see it is true. But I remember records should be initialized with `Initialize` (or is it `Finalize`?)

Comment: True. Will delete

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> My question: is it guaranteed that each record element will be initialized with default values?

Yes, this is guaranteed.

The `SetLength` [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SetLength) says (my emphasis):

> Existing elements in the array are preserved and **newly allocated space is set to 0 or nil**.